# Alterar um atributo de um elemento de XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Tenho o seguinte XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
  -<NewDataSet>
    -<xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" id="NewDataSet">
      -<xs:element msdata:Locale="" msdata:MainDataTable="INFO" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
        -<xs:complexType>
          -<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            -<xs:element msdata:Locale="" name="INFO">
```

Preciso de alterar a última linha com XSLT para onde se lê `name="INFO"` ficar `name="INFO2"`. Já tentei várias transformações e nenhuma funciona :(

Comment: Mostre o xslt que está usando

Comment: Qual o critério que você usa para selecionar o elemento que precisa ser alterado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para substituir o valor de um atributo é preciso antes de tudo localizar o seu elemento através de uma expressão XPath, que será passada para o template da folha de estilos.

Vou supor que a seleção é feita pelo nome do `xs:element` externo que tem um atributo `name`com o valor de `NewDataSet`. Neste caso, o XPath para localizar este elemento é:

```
//xs:element[@name='NewDataSet']
```

Isto pode ser passado para o atributo `match` do `xsl:template` sem o `//` e será o contexto usado dentro do template. Você também pode usar um contexto mais específico, continuando o path até o elemento onde está o atributo que você quer mudar:

```
xs:element[@name='NewDataSet']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element
```

Conhecendo o elemento que você quer alterar, você precisa então definir dois templates na folha de estilos. Um para copiar todos os outros elementos e atributos, e um para selecionar o elemento acima e trocar o seu atributo. É preciso também declarar os namespaces que você está usando, para que as expressões XPath qualificadas acima funcionem.

O XSLT abaixo faz a substituição usando os critérios descritos acima:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='NewDataSet']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">INFO2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'name']|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

O primeiro template copia todos os elementos e atributos para a saída. O segundo substitui o valor do atributo e copia os sub-elementos e outros atributos de `xs:element` se eles existirem.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! É possível fazer uma 2ª transformação utilizando o mesmo ficheiro XSLT? Preciso adicionalmente de fazer a seguinte alteração: <xsl:template match="INFO">
        <INFO2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></INFO2>
    </xsl:template>